# How many instances are there, of static variables declared in a method?

Tags: c++, static, static-methods, static-members

In this case, there should be only one or zero instances of the static variable. It depends whether `f()` has been called or not.

```
void f() 
{
    static int a;
}
```

But how many instances of the static variable are there if `f()` is a method?

```
class A
{
    void f()
    {
        static int a;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as for the function: 0 or 1. It is very easy to check too:

```
class A
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        static int a = 0;
        ++a;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();
    a.f();
    A b;
    b.f();
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

However, if you derieve from `class A` and make the function virtual like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        static int a = 0;
        ++a;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        static int a = 0;
        ++a;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};
```

then the `a` variable will be different for the base and for each derived class (because the functions are different too).

Answer (score 2):

The same... being a member function is orthogonal to being a static local.